How to change what RenderTarget2D display in Monogame?
I am developing a Monogame project where I have a map class like this:
public class Map
{
    private RenderTarget2D _target;
    public const int TILE_SIZE = 128;
    public static readonly int[,] tiles = {
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    };
    Texture2D wall = Globals.Content.Load<Texture2D>("wall");

    public Map()
    {
        _target = new(Globals.GraphicsDevice, tiles.GetLength(1) * TILE_SIZE, tiles.GetLength(0) * TILE_SIZE);
        Activate();
        DrawMap();
        Globals.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
    }

    public void Explosion()
    {
        tiles[0,0] = 0;
        Activate();
        DrawMap();
        Globals.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
    }

    public void Activate(){
        Globals.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(_target);
        Globals.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);
    }

    public void DrawMap(){
        Globals.SpriteBatch.Begin();
        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tiles.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (tiles[i, j] == 1)
                {
                    var posX = j * TILE_SIZE;
                    var posY = i * TILE_SIZE;
                    Globals.SpriteBatch.Draw(wall, new Vector2(posX, posY), Color.White);
                }

            }
        }
        Globals.SpriteBatch.End();
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        Globals.SpriteBatch.Draw(_target, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
    }

    public void Update()
    {

    }
}

The tiles matrix is the layout of the map, lets say there is an explosion at tile[0,0] (Explosion method). How can I redraw the changed map to the screen? Right now it crashes can't figure out why. There is also a GameManager class where i create a map instance and call it's Draw() method but that's it.
I tried playing around with the SpriteBatch.Begin - End, but it doesn't seems to be the problem, The crash happens after calling Activate() method the second time. Maybe there is something I don't understand about RenderTarget2D is the problem here.

I can't spot anything obviously wrong. Can you add the text or the info the debugger tells you when it crashes? I assume you debug in Debug mode, otherwise it is hard to tell what exactly leads to a crash .

Well I got an Exception, but don't really know what it means. Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in MonoGame.Framework.dll. It triggerd at line Globals.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(_target); in Activate(), but only the second time.

You could try if it makes a difference to create the RenderTarget2D with all parameters (see possible function alternatives with alt-click on the new operator) and set the last parameter as 'RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents'. Unfortunately, I also can't be sure about the cause with the given information.

Small addition: also be sure (if not already the case) to call any kind of draw method only from within the Draw function of the main Game class.
